# Postgres 8.3 on Ubuntu. Where are the server logs?

Tags: logging, postgresql

Postgres 8.3 on Ubuntu. Where are the server logs?

I'm sure there must be a standard place it puts them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Did you have a look in the `/var/log` directory? I assume the logs are placed in `/var/log/postgresql`. But you can also check the PostgreSQL configuration files for the logfile settings.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable logging from /etc/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf then you'll able to see logs on this directory /var/log/postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in /var/log would be my guess. That's the standard place for logs in Debian, which Ubuntu is derived from.